# Class that calculates the total weekly wage

Tags: c++, class

Want to create a class that calculated the weekly wage with the over hours, but it outputs something strange: -1.07374e+08. Any help?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Wage {
public:
Wage(int hW, int h) {
    hWage = hW;
    hours = h;
}
void setWage() {
    if (hours <= 40) {
        tWage = hours * tWage;
    } else {
        tWage = hours * hWage + (hours - 40) * (hWage * 1.5);
    }
}
float getWage() {
    return tWage;
}

private:
float tWage;
float hWage;
float hours;
};

int main() {

Wage w(10, 8);
cout << w.getWage() << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: The member `tWage` isn't initialized but read in `setWage()`. If the value shall be zero at creation of the instance, set it so in the constructor.

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger? What has that told you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`w.tWage` hasn't been initialised. You're asking for `w.getWage()`, but the function to calculate the value hasn't been called yet.

Answer (score 1):

You never called `w.setWage()` before calling `w.getWage()`.

Comment: Yes, that's true. We all search for a bug, but you the most important one.